# How to push and install APK files from a PC over Internet?

Tags: applications, installation, apk

I want to push **AND INSTALL** apk files from PC like Play Store does (when I send install signal from web interface). How to do this?

**Note:** The PC and Android device may not be in same Wi-Fi network. So, I am asking for solution over Internet.
I am rooted..

Comment: Technically this ends up in a clone of Google Play: Set-up a server that provides one or more APKs. On client side install an APK manually that connects to the server and downloads and installs new APKs automatically. Everything is possible but I don't know an ready-to-use solution.

Comment: @Robert If an app can make use of a Dropbox folder to install all APKs in it automatically, there's no need to setup own server for this.

Comment: You are right, that is the reason I wrote "the server" and not "own server".

Comment: @Robert You said, "set-up a server". Are you thinking about setup a server for another one?

Answer (score 1):

Setup a VPN! Having your phone rooted will let you install OpenVPN . You should setup a server (and connect it too to the VPN) and your phone will be your client.

Then you'll have a server and a client in the same network so you can use adb commands! Push, pull, install...