# How to Install apks from computer?

Tags: apk

Was just wondering is it possible to Install apks directly from pc. I am not talking it through Google play . I have a rooted device.

Comment: Please see: [How can I install an app given only its APK file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5566/16575) / [How do I properly install a system app given its .apk?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27/16575) / [How to push and install APK files from a PC over Internet?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26045/16575) and [several more](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+install+apk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways.

**ADB is the first one.** By connecting your phone to your PC with USB Debugging enabled and ADB installed, you can simply run the following command (where 'android' is the location of your ADB or platform-tools installation and 'appname' is the name of the apk to install):

```
C:\android> adb.exe install c:\somefolder\appname.apk
```

This assumes Windows. For other operating systems the process is basically the same just executing adb install in the terminal in the folder where adb is installed using the appropriate path name to the app in the format of your OS (forward vs back slashes).

**The next way is with an app.** Apps like [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) will let you install apps and much more over wifi (for free, or you can pay a fee and use mobile network). AirDroid is simple. Install the app on your phone and open it and then go to http://web.airdroid.com/ from the same wifi network and follow the instructions to connect. If you sign up, you don't have to use the Pin or qr code each time, just log in. Then you can install apps and more from the desktop like interface.

If you haven't checked it out, AirDroid is very useful.

Comment: any simpler app that is specialized for installing apks usingdata cable?

Comment: I don't know of one, and a quick Google search didn't turn any up, but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist. The adb method is built into Android. The other option is to just copy the app to your phone's storage when it is connected to the PC and then just use a file manager to browse your internal storage and launch the app. It will then install like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just copy that apk file to your SD card and just tap, its start installing.